# How to convert a tuple to a list of tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

For example I have a tuple `(1,2,3)`, how to convert it into `[(1,2,3)]`?
I tried `list` method but it seems doesn't work.

```
l = (1,2,3) -> l =[(1,2,3)]
```

Comment: Why not simply `[l]`?

Answer (score 5):

Just put the tuple into a list.

```
l = [(1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: Not  a good solution. You'll have to write the tuple yourself. `l=[l]` works better

Answer (score 0):

```
l_tuple = (1, 2, 3)
l_list = [l_tuple]
l_list_items = list(l_tuple)

>>> print l_list
[(1, 2, 3)]

>>> print l_list_items
[1, 2, 3]
```

Not that there is a difference between using the square braces and the `list()` function to construct your list.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = (1,2,3)
>>> print list([l])
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty list and append tuple to it.

```
>>>t = (1,2,3)
>>>a = []
>>>a.append(t)
>>>a
[(1,2,3)]
>>>
```